# How do inductors store energy?

Tags: induction

I know that in capacitors, when we create a potential difference between the two plates, and then cut off the current, the electrons stay there and this energy is stored. But what is the similar mechanism that inductors store energy? The inductors have electrons running across them and because their spiral movement, this movement causes a magnetic field to be created. But if we cut off current, will the magnetic field stay there? Also, if we continuously give current to an inductor, it will create a continuously increasing magnetic field until it reaches a maximum and stop the flow of current, similar to what capacitors do?

Comment: As capacitors store energy in the electric field, so inductors store energy in the magnetic field.  Both capacitors and inductors have many uses with time-varying currents.   If you slow or stop the current through an inductor there is a response which works against the change; see Lenz' Law,

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=inductor+energy

Comment: The energy in a capacitor can be thought as being stored in the electric field.  The energy is stored in the magnetic field for an inductor which needs to have charges moving, an electric current.  
So if the current is reduced or eventually made zero the magnetic field would be reduced and so the energy stored in the inductor decreases.

Comment: so inductors don't store energy permanently like capacitors after current ceases

Comment: Inductor energy is proportional to current squared. To stop the current you have to take the energy away. That is why inductors oppose changes in current.

Comment: If you want to store energy in an inductor you run current trough it and then you short the inductor. The energy will be stored in the magnetic field and the current will keep flowing, at least for a while. Unlike with many capacitors this is only a short term storage (it works well for $\mu s$ to $ms$, which is used in switching mode power supplies. The reason for that is the finite resistance of the winding, which will cause an $I^2R$ loss. If you have a superconducting inductor, then you can store energy for a virtually arbitrary long time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows insufficient research efforts as said by Alfred Centauri.

Comment: user36790 you are ignorant

Comment: Voting to leave open because research effort is not a criterion for closing.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161457/how-does-an-inductor-store-energy

Answer (score 1):

Like Peter Diehr says in the comments, the way to see the duality between inductors and capacitors is that capacitors store energy in an electric field, inductors store energy in a magnetic field.

> But if we cut off current, will the magnetic field stay there?

No, the magnetic field is proportional to the current, so if you stop the current then the field will go to zero. But because the stored energy is proportional to the current, you actually can't stop the current without doing something to remove the stored energy.

In duality to how a capacitor can store energy when no current is passing through it, and inductor can continue to pass a current (and thus store energy) when the potetntial difference across it goes to zero.

To stop the current, you have to apply a potential opposing the established current flow, which will mean the inductor delivers energy to the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score -3):

The electric field of a charge is uniformly distributed on the charge and once separated, this separation state holds (not taking in account some leaks because even a capacitor is not insulated perfectly).

The reason for the magnetic field in coils is the alignment of the magnetic dipole moments of the accelerated electrons. Cutting the electric potential difference, the involved electrons after some time get misaligned again and equally distributed in all directions. To preserve the magnetic field it is necessary to cool the coil below some temperature and to use superconducting wires. A superconducting coil hold his magnetic field even after the external electric potential difference was cut.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense to me (e.g., the first sentence on the "leaks," how superconductors come into play). Could you add some more details?

Comment: @KyleKanos Leaks means that nothing is perfectly insulated and even a capacitor loose charges.

Comment: @KyleKanos A [supersonducting magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet) holds its magnetic field even after the applied potential difference is cut and the coil is an insulated system.